# Support retina iPhone and low-def ipad but not retina iPad in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an app that uses Cocos2D which supports normal and retina iPhones.  I'm trying to port it so it also supports the iPad.  However, I do not want to support the retina iPad (because I do not have high enough resolution images).  Is there a way to do this?

When I run the app on the iPad simulator things work well, but on the retina iPad things are broken. (It takes the low-def iPad app and runs it in a corner of the screen instead of scaling it up). Ideally, I would just scale up all the low-def iPad images so it works for the retina iPad.

Comment: Apple requires that you support the full retina screen of all retina devices. Your app will most likely be rejected if the graphics on the retina iPads appear to be scaled up.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of the Apple policy change... looks like I'll have to make it work

Comment: This went into affect May 1st along with requiring full support of the 4" screens of the iPhone 5 and 5th gen iPod touch.

Comment: which cocos2d version are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in AppDelegate, if you are using cocos2D template, then in Appdelegate you will find this line

```
if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
            CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```

change the above lines to the lines below.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported"); 
}
```

Else you search for the this statement through the project

```
[director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES];
```

change that to

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
            CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported"); 
    }
```